# Configuring cloudwatch logs to elk

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops, elastic-stack, amazon-cloudwatch, bitnami

I want to setup a centralized logging system for aws.so what all configuration to be done in elk to get logs from cloudwatch? . Currently i have an instance running based on bitnami elk image

Comment: What have you tried ?

Comment: @user3287355 Hi, i currently installed logstash,elastic search,kiabana, in that ec2 insatnce . Is it possible to get logs from cloudwatch using log stash